IIS App Pool Identity - Can we use external account?
We are building an application with multiple microservices using .Net Core. In the startup code for each service, we fetch the configuration details such as database connection string from the azure key vault. While accessing the key vault, we are passing in the default azure credentials object.
Running the service from visual studio doesn't cause any issues as I have already added my Azure Account in visual studio. However, there is an issue while trying to run the service by hosting it on IIS as I believe it is trying to access the key vault using IIS app pool identity account.
Is there any way we can configure an external account (e.g. Azure Account) in the app pool identity?
I tried setting it under Custom Account but didn't work.
P.S. I'm using IIS 10.0
Tried setting my azure account under custom account for app pool identity, but it didn't work, as soon as I launch the site, the app pool is stopping automatically. (Maybe it is not able to reach out to the mentioned account)

How did you set up the Custom Account in the app pool identity? Besides that, you are accessing from outside, is your firewall blocking it?

@samwu I'm not accessing the site from the outside. I'm accessing it on my machine only. I set the custom account from the app pool advanced settings, by providing the username and password.
